# Linq orderby sum of sublist item compared to mainlist item

Tags: linq, sql-order-by, sublist

I have a issue I havn't yet been able to find a solution on. To simplify the issue: I have two SQL tables and I'm using LinQ to SQL. The two tables represents Courses, where CourseType contains CourseName and TotalSpots, and CourseInstance contains CourseDate, AmountSignedUp and a refrence to CourseType. There's a one to many relation between CourseType and CourseInstance.

Now what I need help with is the Linq query/Lambda expression to sort both CourseType and CourseInstance (if it's posible). I want the CourseType to be sorted after how many in total free spots (calculated from every CourseInstance under CourseType; CourseType.TotalSpots - CourseInstance.SignedUp), where the CourseType with most free spots shows first. I want CourseInstance to be sorted simlar, by how many free spots that CourseInstance has (CourseType.TotalSpots - CourseInstance.AmountSignedUp).

I can't get my head around how to solve this. I've looked at simlar questions and issue and this is what I've made so far, just to give a basic idea:

Edit: I've done this code so far which will sort the CourseType correctly. I'm not sure how I can get the CourseInstance sublist sorted (CourseType.CourseInstance). I guess I'll have to do it later in the code when I'm converting it to a list unless someone has a good solution for this. I could do it as Arion suggested, why I'll mark his answer.

```
var result= (
        from c in _db.CourseType
        orderby ((c.TotalSpots * c.CourseInstance.Count) - c.CourseInstance.Sum(
                                ci => (ci.AmountSignUp ?? 0))) descending
        select c
     );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not really sure what you want. But kinda sounds like you want to order by the `c.TotalSpots - ci.AmountSignedUp`. So is not this enough?

```
var result=(
    from ct in db.CourseType
    join ci in db.CourseInstance
        on ct.SomeCourseTypeKey equals ci.SomeCourseInstanceKey
    orderby c.TotalSpots - ci.AmountSignedUp
    select new {ci,ct}
    );
```

where db is the linq data context.

Or if `c.TotalSpots` and `ci.AmountSignedUp` is `nullable` then like this:

```
var result=(
        from ct in db.CourseType
        join ci in db.CourseInstance
            on ct.SomeCourseTypeKey equals ci.SomeCourseInstanceKey
        orderby (c.TotalSpots??0) - (ci.AmountSignedUp??0)
        select new {ci,ct}
        );
```

I am still not sure want you want but. You could do this:

```
var result=(
    from ct in db.CourseType
    orderby ct.TotalSpots
    select new 
    {
        ci,
        CourseInstances=(
            from ci in db.CourseInstance
            where ct.SomeCourseTypeKey == ci.SomeCourseInstanceKey
            orderby ct.TotalSpots- ci.AmountSignedUp
            select ci
        )
    }
    );
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Arion! I would perfer result to only contain CourseType, and not both CourseType and CourseInstance. Reason is CourseInstance will be a sublist to CourseType and then I can just query this sublist when I need the object which contains in it. I would like both the CourseType and sublist CourseInstance to be sorted. Is this posible or is the solution you suggested only way to solve it having both list sorted? Cheers

Comment: So that fixed it for you? @user1350598 : Remember to up vote the answer you think are good. That gives us all a warm fuzzy feeling :P